# T-sql SmallDateTime add day when time passed 23:30

Tags: sql, t-sql, smalldatetime

T-sql SmallDateTime  add day when time passed 23:30

```
declare @sampledate DateTime
set @sampledate='2020-09-18 23:59:53'
select  @sampledate AS Date,
       CAST(@sampledate as DATE) AS CAST_Date,
       CAST(@sampledate as SmallDateTime) CAST_smalldatetime,
   CONVERT(SmallDateTime,@sampledate) Convert_smalldatetime
```

Comment: What does `23:30` have to do with your code sample? What, precisely, is your question?

Answer (score 1):

When converting `datetime` to `smalldatetime`, SQL will round the minute based on the seconds. It works out that 23:59:29.998 and below will round down to 23:59, and 23:59:29.999 and up will round up to tomorrow.

But does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding 30 minutes and converting to a date?

```
convert(date, dateadd(minute, 30, @sampledate)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. Look at Property `Time range` from [MS Docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> 2007-05-09 23:59:59 will round to 2007-05-10 00:00:00